# Graph API: A user without a name

Tags: facebook-graph-api

How is it possible that a user has no name?

For example id: 100004139740839.
This user registered in my application yesterday.

If you try to get data without using an access token, you will receive **false** response.
When I pull data with the user's access token I get following data:

```
{
   "id": "100004139740839",
   "link": "https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100004139740839",
   "timezone": 0,
   "locale": "pt_BR",
   "verified": true,
   "updated_time": "2012-08-10T07:12:01+0000"
}
```

i.e. there is no "name" field.

Comment: Is this the actual user id? I only get false when I try to look it up using the Graph API Explorer, although a user’s basic info should always be available, even without an access token specific to that user. The only thing I could think of why this might be happening is that maybe the account has been deleted/deactivated/blocked already (but then it’d be strange that you can still use a user access token for it).

Comment: Yes, this is actual user ID and i still can use his access token. More then that, this user is admin of some pages that still active.

Comment: In your privacy settings on facebook, you can choose to show up in search results.  This probably affects how the graph api accesses the "public" information.

Answer (score 1):

you get this because the users is a page. if you manage to find out who the actual user is, you'll see that a page with this id belongs to that user. its annoying, and I've yet to find a way to get the actual user using a page id

Comment: Why you think, that user is a page? According to Graph API response, it's human profile. For example, i get "locale" field. You receive that field only for user ID, but not for page ID.